# Is there a way of capturing card payments to be able to process them manually afterwards?

Tags: expresso-store

If the server is set up PCIDSS Compliant and I want to store the card details to be processed using a conventional cart facility, is this possible?

I also need to be able to take direct debit info, can this also be done in some way, or in conjunction with another plugin like freeform etc?

Thanks
Guy

Answer (score 1):

I'd highly recommend *against* storing any card details. It can only go to cause problems. PCI DSS compliance is not just about the server security but even physical security. The premises will need to be highly secure and adhere to compliance levels as well as external locations for backups etc. Everything would need to be encrypted in storage and in transit and then even if you do meet those levels there is always a chance of having something stolen and then you'd be in a LOT of trouble so your insurance would go through the roof too. It really isn't worth it.

If you're using a service such as [Spreedly Core](https://spreedly.com/) then they provide a *Vault* which allows you to retain credit card details for re-use next time via a secure token based system. This puts the responsibility firmly on their shoulders then and is a much better way.

Using Spreedly Core you can then also allow the user to choose their gateway so you can setup a gateway for accepting credit cards and also one for accepting direct debit payments and allow the user to choose or to specify yourself.

Alternatively if you wanted to setup a credit card gateway and then a direct debit gateway individually then that's possible in Store too. [GoCardless](https://gocardless.com/) is a good direct debit gateway if you're UK based and I'd recommend [Dwolla](http://www.dwolla.com/) if you're US based. The GoCardless gateway is already provided as part of store so you can use that out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear whether you want to store credit cards and charge them later, or just initiate a charge and complete it at a later date (usually once you have shipped the items). This is known as separate authorize/capture.

Store doesn't support storing credit cards, but it does support authorize/capture, you just need to enable it under general settings.